# Fade in and move

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a simple div to fade in and move simultaneously. Suppose there is a hidden image at the top and when I click a buton the image should come in the center of the page with fading in effect.

but for me it fades in first and then starts moving...

```
        $('#shelf').fadeIn('fast').animate({
            'bottom': '54%'
            }, 'slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this

```
$('#shelf').fadeIn('fast').animate({
            'bottom': '54%'
            }, {duration: 'slow', queue: false}, function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
```

Comment: Best method IMO

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
$('#shelf').animate({
        'bottom': '54%',
        'opacity': 1
        }, 'slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
});
```

Comment: '#Shelf' is hidden at first. So I need to fade it In first. Anyway thanks for your answer. I made a Up vote for you

Answer (score 1):

jQuery chains events, so it thinks: "Complete fadeIn, then do this animation."

If you include the fade in code (like: `opacity: 100%;`) in the animation, it will do everything at once.

Comment: No, it doesn't think like this, the animate function is not in the callback function of "fadeIn". If it doesn't execute simultaneously, it because fadeIn internally is using animate and so there is an fx event queue order.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery chains the events and runs them in order, which is why the fade happens before the animation.

Here is an example using CSS3 transition property to take care of the animation.

http://jsfiddle.net/jdmiller82/UMVnD/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#shelf')..fadeTo(2000, 1).animate({
            'bottom': '54%'
            }, {duration: 'slow', queue: false}, function() {
            // Animation complete.
});
```

Comment: delete one dot in front of feadTo

Answer (score -2):

Because you put fadeIn() first in the chain.  Try to separate the two into two separate calls:

```
    $('#shelf').fadeIn('fast');

    $('#shelf').animate({
        'bottom': '54%'
        }, 'slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
```

Comment: That is the same thing he has. The animate doesn't wait for fadeIn to finish, only if he did this would that matter: `$('#shelf').fadeIn('fast',function(){ $(this).animate({ 'bottom': '54%' }, 'slow'); });`

Answer (score -3):

Well you have it fading in fast, but moving slow. They both start at the same time, but you notice the fade first.

Make them both the same and they will both appear at the same time.